# Send mail to an IP Address using python

Tags: python, email, ip-address

So I am trying to send mails via a python script. It is working fine using the usual format of the receiver address "user@domain.tld". When I'm now trying to use the script with a receiver "user@[IP-Address] all my debug output looks good and the sendmail method works, but the mail is never received. I get the IP address via dig from my terminal.

This is my method expecting a receiver as parameter (cut some unimportant stuff out and obfuscated the real addresses/credentials)

```
def sendmail(receiver):
    msg = MIMEText('This is the body of the mail.')
    msg['From'] = email.utils.formataddr(('me', myaddr))
    msg['To'] = email.utils.formataddr(('me', receiver))
    msg['Subject'] = "Python Mail Script"


    server = smtplib.SMTP(smtpServer, smtpPort)
    try:
        server.set_debuglevel(True)

        # identify ourselves, prompting server for supported features
        server.ehlo()

        # If we can encrypt this session, do it
        if server.has_extn('STARTTLS'):
            server.starttls()
            server.ehlo() # re-identify ourselves over TLS connection

        server.login("me@...", "...")
        server.sendmail("me@...", toAddr,  msg.as_string())
    finally:
        server.quit()
```

The output I get for sending a message to an IP-Address is (again I obfuscated the smtp server and mail/ip addresses):

```
send: 'ehlo [127.0.1.1]\r\n'
reply: '250-mail.example.de\r\n'
reply: '250-PIPELINING\r\n'
reply: '250-SIZE 102400000\r\n'
reply: '250-VRFY\r\n'
reply: '250-ETRN\r\n'
reply: '250-STARTTLS\r\n'
reply: '250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN\r\n'
reply: '250-AUTH=PLAIN LOGIN\r\n'
reply: '250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES\r\n'
reply: '250-8BITMIME\r\n'
reply: '250 DSN\r\n'
reply: retcode (250); Msg: mail.example.de
PIPELINING
SIZE 102400000
VRFY
ETRN
STARTTLS
AUTH PLAIN LOGIN
AUTH=PLAIN LOGIN
ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
8BITMIME
DSN
send: 'STARTTLS\r\n'
reply: '220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS\r\n'
reply: retcode (220); Msg: 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS
send: 'ehlo [127.0.1.1]\r\n'
reply: '250-mail.example.de\r\n'
reply: '250-PIPELINING\r\n'
reply: '250-SIZE 102400000\r\n'
reply: '250-VRFY\r\n'
reply: '250-ETRN\r\n'
reply: '250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN\r\n'
reply: '250-AUTH=PLAIN LOGIN\r\n'
reply: '250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES\r\n'
reply: '250-8BITMIME\r\n'
reply: '250 DSN\r\n'
reply: retcode (250); Msg: mail.example.de
PIPELINING
SIZE 102400000
VRFY
ETRN
AUTH PLAIN LOGIN
AUTH=PLAIN LOGIN
ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
8BITMIME
DSN
send: 'AUTH PLAIN AHRob21hc0B0b3Jh6feldi5kZQBiYWdpbmVy\r\n'
reply: '235 2.7.0 Authentication successful\r\n'
reply: retcode (235); Msg: 2.7.0 Authentication successful
send: 'mail FROM:<me@example.de> size=234\r\n'
reply: '250 2.1.0 Ok\r\n'
reply: retcode (250); Msg: 2.1.0 Ok
send: 'rcpt TO:<me@[IP-ADDRESS]>\r\n'
reply: '250 2.1.5 Ok\r\n'
reply: retcode (250); Msg: 2.1.5 Ok
send: 'data\r\n'
reply: '354 End data with <CR><LF>.<CR><LF>\r\n'
reply: retcode (354); Msg: End data with <CR><LF>.<CR><LF>
data: (354, 'End data with <CR><LF>.<CR><LF>')
send: 'Content-Type: text/plain; charset="us-ascii"\r\nMIME-Version: 1.0\r\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\nFrom: me <me@example.de>\r\nTo: me <me@[IP-ADDRESS]>\r\nSubject: Python Mail Script\r\n\r\nThis is the body of the mail.\r\n.\r\n'
reply: '250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 4C5A78560196\r\n'
reply: retcode (250); Msg: 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 4C5A78560196
data: (250, '2.0.0 Ok: queued as 4C5A78560196')
send: 'quit\r\n'
reply: '221 2.0.0 Bye\r\n'
reply: retcode (221); Msg: 2.0.0 Bye
```

Anyone seeing any mistake or error?

Edit: Using an own smtp postfix server in the university(unfortunatly no access to the outside world) and sending the mail to user@[IP-ADDRESS] of this very server the mail arrives. Probably another sign that in the problematic case stated above the smtp-server of the receiver just doesn't allow an IP address as destination.

Edit2: /var/log/mail.log

```
mail.log:Sep  9 00:34:06 mail postfix/qmgr[4854]: A30168560199: from=<me@example.de>, size=1197, nrcpt=1 (queue active)

mail.log:Sep  9 00:34:06 mail postfix/smtp[19355]: A30168560199: to=<me@[IP-ADDRESS]>, relay=none, delay=314, delays=313/0.04/0.01/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to IP-ADDRESS[IP-ADDRESS]:25: Connection refused)

mail.log:Sep  9 00:38:31 mail postfix/smtpd[19907]: warning: Illegal address syntax from my_host_where_the_python_script_runs[IP of me] in RCPT command: <me@IP-ADDRESS>
```

So the connection from the SMTP server I am using to the recipient server is refused and 4 minutes later the smtp deamon says it received a wrong syntax even though in the handshake where I am sending via my script it say 250 Ok ... So basically I think the recipient SMTP refuses it.
Thx guys

Comment: Although this is technically supported by the RFC, it's possible the email host simply doesn't accept messages sent in this fashion. This is a possible spam tactic to send messages to public IPs that accept inbound SMTP connections, without actually knowing a valid destination domain.

Comment: What does the mail log show? (If unix, /var/log/maillog)

Comment: The problem is I currently have no access to the smtp-server I am using to send these mails. Contacting the admin so he might send me  the log. @admdrew you got a valid point as well, this might be a problem

Comment: @admdrew, Check this out: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc822.html#appendix-C.5.1 Seems IP address is no longer valid?

Comment: @user3885927 Using an IP address instead of a domain should definitly work in theory as "proved" in my update.

Comment: @user3885927 Not seeing where that document says IPs can't be used.

Comment: @admdrew, I guess it's not invalid but the doc says in CAPs that it's discouraged. Page 30 says: "Note:  THE USE OF DOMAIN-LITERALS IS STRONGLY DISCOURAGED.  It is  permitted  only  as  a means of bypassing temporary system limitations, such as name tables which  are  not complete."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Domain names in email addresses are much like domain names for web sites - a single server at a single IP address is often responsible for many different domain names, and so in those cases you must supply the name in your request. For example, a mail server at `1.2.3.4` may service both `abc.com` and `xyz.com`. If you say `RCPT TO: <joe@[1.2.3.4]>`, the server has no idea if you are trying to reach `joe@abc.com` or `joe@xyz.com`. The server might arbitrarily pick one (and guess wrong), accept the message and drop it, or reject the message.

Unless you have somehow verified with the server operator that the server will deliver `user@[ip]`-addressed messages to the domain you expect, you should not assume that it will.

Comment: `The server might arbitrarily pick one` I'm actually curious if this would ever be the case.